# Standard form for the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4y-2z$

Tags: calculus

Question: show that the points $(x,y,z)$ which satisfy $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4y-2z$
are a sphere by rewriting this equation in the standard form for a sphere.

I know that the standard form for a sphere is
$$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 = R^2.$$

I am not exactly sure how to solve this, I was thinking that the $4y-2z$ are the $b$ and $c$ for the standard form but then would it combine to be $-3y$ and $-z$ or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to complete the square. For example:
$$
z^2+2z=0\iff z^2+2z+1=1\iff (z+1)^2=1.
$$
Can you do the same for $y$?

Edit: when you do it for $y$, you should get
$$
y^2-4y=0\iff y^2-4y+4=4\iff (y-2)^2=4.
$$
That'll get you the formula for a circle that you want.

Comment: why do i have to complete the square?

Comment: Converting to standard form will require you to put everything into the format that completing the square gives you.

Comment: so they when i do it for y i get $(y-2)^2$ = -2 , would the equation then be $x^2$ + $(y-2)^2$ + $(z+1)^2$ = -1?

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Write $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4y-2z$ as $x^2 + y^2-4y + z^2+2z=0$. Hence,$$x^2 + y^2-4y + z^2+2z$$$$=x^2+y^2-4y+(4-4)+z^2+2x+(1-1)$$ $$=x^2+(y^2-4y+4)-4+(z^2+2x+1)-1$$ $$=x^2+(y-2)^2+(z+1)^2-5$$ so that $x^2+(y-2)^2+(z+1)^2=\sqrt{5}^2$. This is the equation of the sphere of radius $\sqrt{5}$ centered at ${(0,2,-1)}$.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to group
all the terms with the same variable together.

From
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4y-2z$
we get
$x^2 + y^2-4y + z^2+2z = 0$.

The next step,
as Ian Coley wrote,
is to complete the square
for each variable.
The general formula is
$v^2+av
=v^2+av + (a/2)^2 - (a/2)^2
=(v+a/2)^2 - a^2/4
$.

In your case,
there are two variable
for which this needs to be done:
$y$ and $z$.

For $y$,
since $a=-4$, we get
$y^2-4y
=(y-2)^2-4
$.

For $z$,
since $a=2$, we get
$z^2+2z
=(z+1)^2-1
$.

Putting these in the equation,
it becomes
$x^2 + (y-2)^2-4 + (z+1)^2-1 = 0$.

Finally,
bringing the constant terms
to the right side,
we get
$x^2 + (y-2)^2 + (z+1)^2 = 4+1=5$.

From this,
we see that the sphere
has center
$(0, 2, -1)$
and radius
$\sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

x^2+y^2+z^2=4y-2z......(1)
Now rearranging the terms we get:
x^2+y^2-4y+z^2+2z=0
Now we have to make them perfect square
x^2+y^2-4y+4-4+z^2+2z+1-1=0
Then We get
x^2+(y-2)^2+(z+1)^2-5=0
Or
x^2+(y-2)^2+(z+1)^2=5
Therefore it is a sphere  having centre (0,2,-1) and radius 5^0.5.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! We use [Mathjax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on this site. Read the [Mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to use Mathjax, and if you don't know how to show a certain symbol, you can use [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), a tool that shows you the Mathjax representation of a symbol you draw. In your case though, just put dollar signs around your equation and add newlines to make it look nice.